# React Native Network Fails On Android 9

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

> Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)

I use fetch to connect and retrieve data from https Url. 
On the first try, the connection takes long and the request fails. 
But when I click the second time, request succeeds. Release and Debug apks has the same result.

the only log I could get as an error is above.
I have already added the following to the manifest

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 tools:targetApi="28"
```

Also, I should add that when sending requests if I disconnect the device from the internet and reconnect the phone, request succeeds.

Here is Manifesto

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.weecomicustomernative">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:targetApi="28">
        <activity
            android:name="com.weecomicustomernative.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCviF26pcJZtKxFx1koGhhJLbwC4bLDTBs" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is package.json file

```
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.3",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.6.1",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-camera": "^3.11.1",
"react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
"react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
"react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.26.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-image-placeholder": "^1.0.14",
"react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
"react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
"react-native-permissions": "^2.0.6",
"react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-pull-to-refresh": "^2.1.3",
"react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.3.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-s3-upload": "0.0.12",
"react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
"react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^2.0.3",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
"react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"redux": "^4.0.4"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your RN version?

Comment: "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5", @alvaropaco

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this work around: add the codes in your main AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
    <manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> .... <application 
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> ... 
    </application> </manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using android emulator? This is connect to your network? Are using http or https?

Comment: Did you have setted the network state permission? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: also in some cases you may need to set android:targetSandboxVersion to 1; current default value is 2 which set useClearTextTraffic=false by default.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> just added, I use https,

Comment: And are you using a emulator? This is connect to the same network?

Comment: On the emulator, I dont get any problem, But when I use a Physical device It fails. I have used axios but some issue. Do you think this is a cache issue, should I delete caches,I use android studio to install app

Comment: And the physical device is in the same network? Apparently this is not a problem with your implementation.

Comment: I havent implemented 'useClearTextTraffic=false ' yes they are on same network

Comment: The default value for useClearTraffic is "false". You can set the cleartextTrafficPermitted=”true” too, to permit clear traffic. This article explain pretty good: https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6

Comment: As I read,  since I use Https I dont have to use usesCleartextTraffic or other things like that

Comment: But you need to have a self-signed certificate to work as well.